# How to debug this 'SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause' error in MySQL 5.7?

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this error

> query failed: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'spidersc_exchanger2018.exchangerix_exchanges.exchange_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Here is my code

```
<?php
        $ee = 0;
        $res_query3 = "SELECT *, sum(exchange_amount) exchange_amount, sum(receive_amount) receive_amount FROM exchangerix_exchanges WHERE date_sub(curdate(), interval 7 day) <= created AND status='confirmed' GROUP BY from_currency, to_currency ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 7";
        $res_result3 = smart_mysql_query($res_query3);

                $res2_query = "SELECT * FROM exchangerix_reviews r LEFT JOIN exchangerix_exchanges e ON r.exchange_id=e.exchange_id WHERE r.status='active' ORDER BY r.added LIMIT ".HOMEPAGE_REVIEWS_LIMIT;
                $res2_result = smart_mysql_query($res2_query);
                $total2_res = mysqli_num_rows($res2_result);
                $cc = 0;

                if ($total2_res > 0)
                {
            ?>
```

Comment: A good rule of thumb is NEVER use `SELECT *`

Comment: What fields in the exchangerix_exchanges table actually get used by whatever PHP code uses the results set?

Answer (score 0):

The asterisk in select * probably returns columns besides from_currency and to_currency (the keys you aggregate on in the group by clause).

Do it like `select from_currency, to_currency, sum(exchange_amount)...`

Comment: @John that simply cannot be true

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to clear this is either remove full_group by clause or add all selecting column in group by

```
 $res_query3 = "SELECT  sum(exchange_amount) exchange_amount, sum(receive_amount) receive_amount FROM exchangerix_exchanges WHERE date_sub(curdate(), interval 7 day) <= created AND status='confirmed' GROUP BY exchange_amount,receive_amount ,from_currency, to_currency ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 7";
```

or
to cancel full group by clause execute below query

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));



 $res_query3 = "SELECT  *,sum(exchange_amount) exchange_amount, sum(receive_amount) receive_amount FROM exchangerix_exchanges WHERE date_sub(curdate(), interval 7 day) <= created AND status='confirmed' GROUP BY exchange_amount,receive_amount ,from_currency, to_currency ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 7";
```

Remember it will be effect till you restart mysql. if its restarted then default setting will restored